# Can you have a GetFeature response from GeoServer without coordinates in the response?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, coordinates, getfeature

I have following URL of a GeoServer WFS layer; it takes very long time to get a response

http://54.225.240.244:8080/envision/BaseMaps/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=BaseMaps%3AINGAA_PIPES9DecNew&outputFormat=json

I get following response from GeoServer.

> geometry_name":"geom","properties":{"gid":3,"Name":"NGTL","folderpath":"INGAA_pipes/TransCanada/NGTL/NGTL","symbolid":2,"altmode":-1,"base":0E-11,"clamped":0,"extruded":0,"snippet":null,"popupinfo":"{\"owner\":\"TransCanada\",\"system\":\"NGTL\",\"webpage\":[\"www.transcanada.com\"]}","shape_leng":185.771114595}},{"type":"Feature","id":"INGAA_PIPES9DecNew.4","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-92.12717838899994,31.63917508000003],[-92.14159562999998,31.617752779000057],[-92.16680984799996,31.579814893000048],[-92.21483079699999,31.53992164600004]],[[-95.81837409699995,39.662585352000065],[-95.81917758399999,39.66816340400004],[-95.82365707699995,39.67032394000006],[-95.82334205299998,39.677685806000056]],[[-99.44366675499998,35.49866045500005],[-99.43912620699996,35.49862043600007],[-99.43753177499997,35.499503152000045],[-99.43609020699995,35.50030088200003]]]}

The length of the coordinates is too much long in the response. And it is very time consuming too.

So how can I apply filter in the URL to get name only and exclude coordinates from whole response?

e.g. here in the response the name in the response is "Name":"NGTL"

Comment: This must be a duplicate question but the key is to list the propertynames http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&outputformat=JSON&propertyname=STATE_NAME,FAMILIES,MALE,HOUSHOLD&BBOX=-91.51,36.98,-87.5,42.5,EPSG:4326.  Very slow service means usually that there is something wrong with the data like bad indexes or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible with a GetFeature request using the `propertyName` parameter.

See the example from the [Geoserver docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#getfeature):

> To restrict a GetFeature request by attribute rather than feature, use the propertyName key in the form propertyName=attribute. You can specify a single attribute, or multiple attributes separated by commas. To search for a single attribute in all features, the following request would be required:

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=2.0.0&
  request=GetFeature&
  typeNames=namespace:featuretype&
  propertyName=attribute
```

In your situation you would use something like  `propertyName=Name` to get only the name attribute.